# bootstrap animationing tab contents script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i am using the bootstrap tabs component in one of my projects , now i wanted to add some animations to my bootstrap tabs , below is the HTML code :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#sectionA">General fitness</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionB">Cardio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionC">weight training</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionD">weight loss</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right animated bounceInLeft">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 animated bounceInRight" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                        <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionD" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                        <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" >
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now everything works fine , notice how i am adding an animation to `<img>` and the 2nd `<div class="col-md-5">` .

below  is the script i wrote for the animations to apply , everytime a tab is clicked :

Jquery script :

```
$('#myTab').on('click' , 'li a' , function(){

    $this = $(this);
    var str_href = $this.attr('href'); 

      str_image      = str_href + ' ' + 'img';
      str_contentdiv = str_href + ' ' + '.add-animation';

      $(str_image).removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
      $(str_contentdiv).removeClass('animated bounceInRight');

      setTimeout(function(){
          $(str_image).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
          $(str_contentdiv).addClass('animated bounceInRight'); 

           setTimeout( function(){
              $(str_image).removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
              $(str_contentdiv).removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
           }, 2000);
      }, 100);  

});
```

its short and sweet , the problem is for removal of the class the setTimeout function takes 2 secound , which means that if the user turns out to be a click maniac , the animations won't run , the reason , i can't lover the 2 secounds rule is that , the animation runs for 2 secound .

I would be grateful if somebody can help me join the missing peice here , I.E. how do i make the animations appear everytime a tab is clicked ??

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: The animation is an animation _(using a keyframe)_ or is a transition?

Answer (score 1):

Add an event lister on the element for the `animationend`/`transitionend` events
first obtain the transition end name with the properly prefix. (Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/) or read [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback) to implement the logic without Modernizr to obtain the event name with prefix)

```
var transEndEventNames = {
    'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',// Saf 6, Android Browser
    'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',      // only for FF < 15
    'transition'       : 'transitionend'       // IE10, Opera, Chrome, FF 15+, Saf 7+
},
transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed('transition') ];
```

Then add the eventListener with the callback

```
element.addEventListener(transEndEventName, transitionEndCallback);
```

Also you can just implement your desired animation when the element becomes active, only once

```
#myTab.active img {
  animation: bounce-left-right 2s ease 1; //Actually is 1 by default so it's not necessary 
}
@keyframe {
  0% {//bounce left animation}
  100% {//bounce right animation}
}
```